# TypeError: init_animals() takes 1 positional arguments but 2 were given

Tags: python, class, methods, typeerror, init

I know this title look familiar to some old questions, but i've looked at every single one of them, none of them solves. 
And here is my codes:

```
class Island (object):E,W,R,P
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.init_animals(y)
  def init_animals(y):
    pass

isle = Island(x,y)
```

However, i got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<stdin>", line 3, in __init__
TypeError: init_animals() takes 1 positional arguments but 2 were given
```

Please tell me if i got any mistakes, im so confused by this. 
Best regards

Comment: `def init_animals(self, y):`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add `self` as the first argument of `init_animals`:

```
def init_animals(self, y):
    pass
```

[`self`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/python-self-explained) (similar to `this` in Java) is the instance of the class.  Every time you call a method within the class, `self` is sent to that method as the first argument.

Comment: So sry to make such mistake, thank you so much